# Creating a vector of class pointers inside another class?

Tags: c++, class

I'm running in to an issue with two classes that I created. It's a simple sports season program. I created one class called Season which is creating a vector of pointers to Game objects. The compiler is complaining about Game being an undeclared identifier even though I have the class defined and tested that it worked.

How come the Game class can not be used in the Season class or how can I get them to be used (maybe nest it in the public part of Season don't know if that would be good or bad)?

```
class Season
{
public:
    Season();
    void add_game(int number, string a, int a_score, string b, int b_score);

private:
    vector<Game*> games;
    int game_high_score;
    string game_high_score_team;
    int season_high_score;
    string season_high_score_team;
    string champion;
};

Season::Season()
{
    int game_high_score = -2;
    string game_high_score_team = "Unknown";
    int season_high_score = -2;
    string season_high_score_team = "Unknown";
    string champion = "Unknown";
}

void Season::add_game(int number, string a, int a_score, string b, int b_score)
{
    Game* temp_game = new Game(number, a, b, a_score, b_score);
    games.push_back(temp_game);
}

string Season::toStr() const
{
    stringstream out;

    out << "Number of games in the season: " << games.size() << endl
        << "game_high_score_team: " << game_high_score_team
        << "\tScore: " << game_high_score_team << endl
        << "season_high_score: " << season_high_score
        << "\tScore: " << season_high_score << endl
        << "champion: " << champion << endl;

    return out.str();
}

// Game class stores values and has functions for each game of the season
class Game
{
public:
    Game();
    Game(int number, string a, string b, int a_score, int b_score);
    string winner(string a, string b, int a_score, int b_score);
    string toStr() const;
    string get_team_a() const;
    string get_team_b() const;
    int get_team_a_score() const;
    int get_team_b_score() const;
    string get_winner() const;
    int get_top_score() const;

private:
    int game;
    string team_a;
    string team_b;
    int team_a_score;
    int team_b_score;
    string won;
    int top_score;
};

Game::Game()
{
    game = -1;
    team_a = "";
    team_b = "";
    team_a_score = -1;
    team_b_score = -1;
    won = "";
    top_score = -1;
}

Game::Game(int number, string a, string b, int a_score, int b_score)
{
    game = number;
    team_a = a;
    team_b = b;
    team_a_score = a_score;
    team_b_score = b_score;
    won =  winner(team_a, team_b, team_a_score, team_b_score);
}

string Game::winner(string a, string b, int a_score, int b_score)
{
    if (a_score > b_score)
    {
        top_score = a_score;
        return a;
    }
    else if (a_score < b_score)
    {
        top_score = b_score;
        return b;
    }
    else
    {
        top_score = a_score;
        return "Tie";
    }
}

string Game::toStr() const
{
    stringstream out;

    out << "Game #" << game << endl
        << "team_a: " << team_a << "\tScore: " << team_a_score << endl
        << "team_b: " << team_b << "\tScore: " << team_b_score << endl
        << "Won: " << won << "\t TopScore: " << top_score << endl;
    return out.str();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    string file_name;
    Season sport;
    file_name = "season.txt"

    ifstream fin(file_name);
    if (fin.fail())
    {
        cout << "Could not read file: " << file_name << endl;
    }

    if (fin.is_open())
    {
        string temp;
        getline(fin, temp);

        int game;
        string a;
        string b;
        int a_score;
        int b_score;
        while (!fin.eof())
        {
            fin >> game >> a >> a_score >> b >> b_score;
            sport.add_game(game, a, b, a_score, b_score);
        }

        // close the input stream from the file.
        fin.close();
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would have been very helpful if you had reduced the size of your program to just the error. By deleting everything that wasn't part of the problem, you could have reduced your program to about 10 lines. This would have made the error easier for me to find, and, potentially, easier for you to find yourself. For more information on this debugging technique, see http://sscce.org/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler reads your program line-by-line, starting at the beginning. At the point where you first reference `Game`:

```
vector<Game*> games
```

you have not yet declared `Game`.

You must either move your `Game` declaration prior to `Season`, or you must *forward-declare* `Game`.

To forward-declare `Game`, add this declaration prior to the definition of `Session`:

```
class Game;
```

Comment: I didn't know I had to prototype the class. Thank you for letting me know.

Answer (score 1):

When `Season` is defined, there is still no information about a future definition of a class `Game`. You have to forward declare `Game` before `Season`:

```
class Game;
```

This will let you use it in context where an incomplete type is allowed. It may make more sense to define `Game` before `Season`, to start with.